# ng-if is not working inside ng-repeat in when bind-html-compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if, ng-bind-html

I have the below code to bind html in my html page,

```
<div bind-html-compile="menuButtonView"></div>
```

I have the below code in my controller,

```
dashboardService.getTemplateMetaData(data.templateCategory)
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.buttonArray = data.btnArray;
    $scope.firstMenuLabel = data.firstMenuLabel;
    if (data.firstMenuLabel) {
      $scope.menuButtonView = '<obl-menu-group label="{{firstMenuLabel}}" icon="fa-pencil-square-o">' +
        '<div data-ng-repeat="btn in buttonArray" >' +
        '<div ng-if="btn.menuTitle !=="Site Settings" ">' +
        '<obl-menu-button label="{{btn.menuTitle}}" icon="fa fa-file-image-o"  menu-function="{{btn.menuFunction}}">' +
        '</obl-menu-button></div>' +
        '<div ng-if="btn.menuTitle ==="Site Settings"">' +
        '<obl-menu-group label="{{btn.menuTitle}}" icon="fa-pencil-square-o"  class="md-sub-menu">' +
        '<obl-menu-button label="Contact Us" icon="fa fa-file-image-o" click-title="contactUs"></obl-menu-button>' +
        '</obl-menu-button></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<obl-menu-group>';
    }
  }).error(function(err) {

  });
}).error(function(err) {

});
```

The ng-if inside the ng-repeat is not working. I can't see anything wrong in this code. Is there a problem with the quotation marks?

Comment: Why do you have HTML in your controller? Can you make a directive for that!

Comment: are you using escape double quotation that "Site Settings"  ?

Comment: Yeah it is working after using escape double quotation in "Site Settings"

Answer (score 0):

use single quote in ng-if

```
'<div data-ng-repeat="btn in buttonArray" >' +
    '<div ng-if="btn.menuTitle !=='Site Settings'">'+
            //Your code
    </div>'
   '<div ng-if="btn.menuTitle ==='Site Settings'">'+
        //Your code
    </div>'
'</div>'
```